# Using blaze-html, how do I create leading non-breaking spaces in html

Tags: html, haskell

Using the package blaze-html, I want to create some html that looks like this

```
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;Some indented text
```

I can't figure out how to create the non-breaking spaces. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: How does the obvious solution not work?

Comment: Why do you ask for the best way to do the wrong thing? A better question would be how to add first-line indent (CSS property `text-indent`) to a block of text.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail I tried several "obvious" (to me at least) solutions, none of which worked. They almost all ended up with "&nbsp;" being displayed in the browser.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Thanks for the pointer. Yes, from reading further, I saw that text-indent was the preferred solution.  For some reason, I still tried to figure out the wrong solution, perhaps out of stubbornness, or perhaps because I thought that someday I might want to insert some other type of "&blah;" symbol into my html.

Answer (score 1):

One way of course is to give a string containing a Haskell-encoded version of that character to `toHtml`.  Another way is to use `preEscapedToMarkup`:

```
preEscapedToMarkup "&nbsp;"
```

Comment: As far as I can tell preEscapedToMarkup is part of blaze-markup, not blaze-html. Actually, I don't know what the difference is between blase-markup and blaze-html and how they relate to each other.

Comment: I also tried "to give a string containing a Haskell-encoded version of that character", which worked, but not the way I expected it to.  I'll show that code in an answer to this question.

Comment: @Tad: blaze-markup provides the general combinators, blaze-html the actual tags and attributes for various standards (html4, html5..)

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice of ertes, I tried "to give a string containing a Haskell-encoded version of the character".  This code is verbose so I could better understand how the types fit together.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

-- * base
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import Data.Char (chr)

-- * text
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as L (Text)
import Data.Text (Text, singleton)
import Data.Text.Lazy.Read (hexadecimal)

-- * blaze-html
import Text.Blaze.Html5
import qualified Text.Blaze.Html5 as H
import Text.Blaze.Renderer.String


nbspHex = "00A0"               :: L.Text -- Unicode codepoint for nbsp
Right (nbspInt, _) = hexadecimal nbspHex
nbspChar = chr nbspInt         :: Char
nbspTxt  = singleton nbspChar  :: Text
nbspHtml = toHtml nbspTxt      :: Html

someHtml ::  Html
someHtml = docTypeHtml $
  body $ do
    p "some text"
    p (nbspHtml <> nbspHtml <> "some indented text")

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let s = renderHtml $ someHtml
  putStrLn s
```

This code displayed the "  some indented text" in the browser as I had hoped, but looking at the html, I didn't see any "@nbsp;", as I had expected.  So this isn't really the answer I was looking for.

Thanks to Jukka for pointing out a better solution.